# x86 Assembly Lanaguage - How to read how many characters are input?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu

I know if you want say two characters input, you'd use:

```
input_str:  .ascii "??"
```

and then later:

```
mov $2, %edx
```

such as in:

```
.data               
input_str:  .ascii "??" 

.text               
.global _start          
_start:             
    mov $3, %eax          # eax = 3 = function number for "read"
    mov $0, %ebx          # ebx = 0 = file descriptor (stdin)
    mov $input_str, %ecx  # ecx = address of input buffer
    mov $2, %edx          # edx = buffer maximum size
    int $0x80             # Call Linux kernel API
                          # eax = error code or number of bytes read
```

etc...

But what if you were asking for a sentence of random length? How do you read how many there after input?

Comment: There's only 2 types of bugs in assembly - comments that don't describe intended behaviour, and instructions that don't do what the comments say they should. I fixed 6 bugs in your example.

Comment: How do you know the sentence is over as input?  Somebody hits the <Return> key usually, which will show up in the input stream.  Or you could base it off of punctuation like '.', '?', '!', etc.  Either way, you don't know the length ahead of time.  You look for an identifier to let you know it is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different tricks to handle random length data and all of them need dynamically allocated memory.

The simplest way to provide it in Linux is to use **sys_brk** function, but it allows only one memory block to be allocated.

There are libraries that provide heap management. One such library, entirely in assembly language is [**FreshLib**](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/index.cgi?page=content/articles/2_FreshLibDoc.txt#H12.1.). Another option is to link with the C standard library.

Then, there are two cases to read the data in the dynamically allocated buffer, depending on whether or not you know the data length in advance (in run time).

### Known data size

It is simple - allocate the buffer with the needed size and read the data entirely.

### Unknown data size - so called stream data

#### Read and then copy

The only possible way to read stream data in the memory is to read a fixed chunks of this data and then to copy it into the dynamically allocated buffer. When the buffer is filled up, you need to reallocate it with bigger size and then to continue until the all data is read.

Note, that the memory reallocation is expensive operation, so it is better to allocate more than needed memory. Common algorithm is to double the size of the allocated memory on every reallocation. Personally I think this strategy is too aggressive and often use multiplying the size by 1.5;

#### Don't read the whole data at all

It is often possible to not read the whole data in the memory, but to process it on the fly as it is read in small fixed chunks. This method needs a little bit more complex algorithms, but has the big advantage to use very small memory, not need dynamically allocated memory and avoids the copy of the data between multiply memory locations.